# Trying to get java and eclipse working on 32 bit Windows

Tags: java, eclipse

So I installed this version of the JDK: **jdk-8u66-windows-i586**  and also installed eclipse for my 32 bit Windows 7. I went into Environment variables and added *C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin* to the end of it so that it now looks like :

```
  OT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROC:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin
```

Yet, java -version on the Command Prompt returns this message:

```
'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

operable program or batch file.

What should I do to get java and eclipse up and running?

Answer (score 2):

Add semicolon `;` before JRE path.

> OT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin

Comment: Did that. Now with : OT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMRO;C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin

it still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Set the path varibale value in System environment variables and once done restart your command prompt and try again.

Also verify the path you are setting for jdb bin is correct.

Answer (score 0):

So it finally works. I searched up the JDK that I downloaded and dragged it onto the command prompt to get its path and added that extension to the end of the 'Path' variable under environment variables. 
Eclipse Mars is now up and running. 
Also during the installation of the JDK, there is a need to explicitly select JRE rather than Development Kit , which is the default.